# T-SQL CTE Compare previous non-NULL and current row to filter out by difference value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursors, recursive

My sample database (in fact a CTE statement data) looks like this:

```
eventdate   val
2012-03-23  3965
2012-03-26  3979
2012-03-27  3974
2012-03-28  3965
2012-03-29  3967
2012-03-30  3959
2012-04-02  3951
2012-04-03  3961
2012-04-04  3944
2012-04-05  3935
2012-04-09  3901
2012-04-10  3822
```

I want to remove the values that are less than 12 in difference. This is my query and output:

```
SELECT
eventdate,
CASE
WHEN ABS(val - LAG(val) OVER (ORDER BY eventdate)) <= 12
THEN NULL
ELSE val
END AS val
FROM tbl_1
ORDER BY eventdate
```

Output:

```
eventdate   val
2012-03-23  3965
2012-03-26  3979
2012-03-27  NULL
2012-03-28  NULL
2012-03-29  NULL
2012-03-30  NULL
2012-04-02  NULL
2012-04-03  NULL
2012-04-04  3944
2012-04-05  NULL
2012-04-09  3901
2012-04-10  3822
```

The problem is that it compares between current and previous row. I need to compare between current and previous non-NULL value, I mean the last value that was not NULLed on the previous step.

This is what I need:

```
eventdate   val
2012-03-23  3965
2012-03-26  3979
2012-03-27  NULL
2012-03-28  3965
2012-03-29  NULL
2012-03-30  NULL
2012-04-02  3951
2012-04-03  NULL
2012-04-04  NULL
2012-04-05  3935
2012-04-09  3901
2012-04-10  3822
```

I tried the following.
I made a self-referenced CTE query as above replacing `THEN NULL` with `THEN LAG(val) OVER (ORDER BY eventdate)` to copy last appropriate value and compare with next. Then remove duplicates. But it deadly loops on `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` with no results at all.

Seems this could be done by CURSOR only.
I need the result set as CTE statement (within the CTE), to use it in next query.

As far as I looked for CURSOR examples they all are done as a final `SELECT` to CTE.
This is not an option for me!

I am running SQL Server 2014.

Many thanks for your help or thoughts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a recursive CTE solution using a technique that Paul White blogged about in [Performance Tuning the Whole Query Plan](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/performance-tuning-whole-plan).

```
declare @T table
(
  Eventdate date index IX_Eventdate clustered,
  Val int
);

insert into @T(Eventdate, Val) values
('2012-03-23',  3965),
('2012-03-26',  3979),
('2012-03-27',  3974),
('2012-03-28',  3965),
('2012-03-29',  3967),
('2012-03-30',  3959),
('2012-04-02',  3951),
('2012-04-03',  3961),
('2012-04-04',  3944),
('2012-04-05',  3935),
('2012-04-09',  3901),
('2012-04-10',  3822);

with C as
(
  select top(1) 
         T.Eventdate,
         T.Val,
         T.Val as PrevVal1,
         T.Val as PrevVal2
  from @T as T
  order by T.eventdate
  union all
  select T.Eventdate,
         T.Val,
         T.PrevVal1,
         T.PrevVal2
  from (
       select T.Eventdate,
              T.Val,
              iif(abs(T.Val - C.PrevVal1) <= 12, C.PrevVal1, T.Val) as PrevVal1,
              iif(abs(T.Val - C.PrevVal1) <= 12, null, T.Val) as PrevVal2,
              row_number() over(order by T.Eventdate) as rn
       from @T as T
       inner join C
         on C.Eventdate < T.Eventdate
       ) as T
  where T.rn = 1
)
select C.Eventdate,
       C.PrevVal2 as Val
from C
order by C.Eventdate
option (maxrecursion 0);
```